# CMake: remove a compile flag from CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE only for a specific target

Tags: cmake, cmake-format

I have

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -m64 -march=native -flto")
```

but I'd like to remove `-flto` for a specific target compilation:

```
file(GLOB TST_SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/x64_test/*.cpp")
add_executable(_x64_test ${TST_SOURCES})
target_compile_options(_x64_test PRIVATE -Wall -DLITTLE_ENDIAN)
target_link_libraries(_x64_test PRIVATE test_iface pthread m)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: just `-fno-lto` ? Using `target_set_property(... INTEPR
OCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION ON)` is preferred

Comment: Yes, in this case you're right! I could deactivate lto optimization using no-lto flag. But in general, is it possible to remove or change a flag?